# CORS Cookies not getting saved in the browser

Tags: http, cookies, browser, cross-domain, credentials

I have a node.js auth api served on `auth.app.loc`, a frontend next.js(react) served on `app.loc` and nginx acting as a reverse proxy.

Any request I make resolves successfuly except, that the cookies are not sent from the server.

Here's my `auth` service summed up.
Served on port 5000 in a docker container.

```js
fastify.register(require('fastify-cookie'));
fastify.register(require('fastify-cors'), { 
  origin: ['http://app.loc', 'http://192.168.0.248:3000'],
  credentials: true,
});

fastify.post('/cookie', async (req, res) => {
  res.setCookie('foo', 'foo');
  res.header('bar', 'bar');
  res.code(204);
});
```

Here's a fragment of my frontend.
Served on port 3000 in a docker container.

```js
const response = await fetch('http://auth.app.loc/cookie', {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  credentials: 'include',
  body: JSON.stringify({login, password})
});
```

And the reverse-proxy config (nginx), also in a docker container.

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        server_name app.loc;
        listen 80;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.0.248:3000;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }

    server {
        server_name auth.app.loc;
        listen 80;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.0.248:5000;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
}
```

Windows hosts file resolves app.loc auth.app.loc to my ip: `192.168.0.248`

Now, making the request from the react app via `fetch` results in:
[image: screenshot from chrome]

But making the same request (via chrome dev tools copy as curl bash) in Postman:

```
curl 'http://auth.app.loc/cookie' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Referer: http://app.loc/signin' -H 'Origin: http://app.loc' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"login":"login","password":"password"}' --compressed --insecure
```

results in a `set-cookie` being passed

[image: screenshot from postman]

Why is it that the `set-cookie` header is not applied when using fetch?

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with `fetch`, but I'm already using `credentials: 'include'`

**@edit**

Acessing the frontend via `http://192.168.0.248:3000/` url, and changing the fetch url to `http://192.168.0.248:5000/cookie` works without an issue. The cookies are getting passed. But why isn't the domain approach working?
[image: cookie getting passed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way...

I wanted to debug it fast and i didn't fill in the **domain** part of **cookie settings**. It seems, that without it, the cookie won't even be saved in the browser, but it's not issue for Postman.

```js
  res.setCookie('foo', 'foo', {
    domain: '.app.loc' //saves everything
  });
```

Comment: res.setCookie is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same issue when I sent cookies and received them in the browser but the browser never applied them. I found that I was missing path parameter. So the following code worked for me.

```
res.setCookie( "authorization", token, { 
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, 
    path: "/",
    httpOnly: true, 
})
```